# Oracle SQL conditional query

Tags: oracle11g, case, conditional-statements

I have a table as ITEM_LOC with the following format:

```
ITEM    LOC    UNIT RETAIL  
100     KS       20
101     JS       22 
102     RS      null
```

I need to find the unit retail,
if the record if present for loc: RS, it should get that. 
If it doesn't exist for RS, it should find for JS.
If it doesn't exist for JS, it should find for KS

and if it doesn't exist of KS, it should return NULL.

How do I go about this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a sub-select, that translates the LOC into an number ordered by priority, and which takes the best numeric value present:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ITEM_LOC
WHERE  decode(LOC, 'RS', 1, 'JS', 2, 'KS', 3, null) =
       (    
         SELECT min(decode(LOC, 'RS', 1, 'JS', 2, 'KS', 3, 4)) 
         FROM   ITEM_LOC
       )
```

Note that if none of these LOC codes exist, you will get an empty result set.
If there are duplicate codes, you can have more than one result.